# HTTP Call using Retrofit fails while same call in Chrome webbrowser works

Tags: android, retrofit, charles-proxy

I'm doing 2 HTTP get requests in Chrome webbrowser. I get back a PDF with the second Get call. When I do the same in an Android App using Retrofit and add the same headers and add the correct mgaParam query parameter, it sends back an Empty 200 OK with content-length = 0

```
@Headers(
        "Content-Type: text/html",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,it;q=0.5",
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36",
        "Referer: https://mijn.belastingdienst.nl/mbd-pmb/pmb.html"
)
@GET("onlineaangifte/ih/2015/olaib.html")
fun get2015TaxReturnToken(@Header("Cookie") cookie: String, @Query("mgaParam") token: String): Single<ResponseBody>


@Headers(
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
        "Purpose: prefetch",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,it;q=0.5"
)
@GET("onlineaangifte/ih/2015/geef-afdruk.do")
fun get2015TaxReturn(@Header("Cookie") cookie: String): Single<ResponseBody>
```

Charles proxy also shows the PDF icon in the correct get call and in the wrong call it doesn't:

[image]